# Stop EC2 Instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a node js application running on EC2. After a certain operation, I want to stop the EC2.

I am using this function to stop EC2

```
const stopInstance = () => {
    // set the region
    AWS.config.update({
        accessKeyId: "MY ACCESS KEY",
        secretAccesskey: "SECRET KEY",
        region: "us-east-1"
    })

    // create an ec2 object
    const ec2 = new AWS.EC2();

    // setup instance params
    const params = {
        InstanceIds: [
            'i-XXXXXXXX'    
        ]
    };

    ec2.stopInstances(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    } else {
        console.log(data);           // successful response
    }  
    });
}
```

When I am running it from EC2, it's giving error

```
 UnauthorizedOperation: You are not authorized to perform this operation.
```

**But when I am running the same code, using the same key and secret from my local machine, It's working perfectly**.

Permissions I have
[image]

Comment: how do you know it's using the same accessKeyId and secretAccesskey?

Comment: @Rico because I generated the key and I am running the application. There is no other developer.

Answer (score 0):

This will be down to the permissions of the IAM user being passed into the script.

Firstly this error message indicates that an IAM user/role was successfully used in the request, but failed to have permissions so that can be ruled out.

Assuming a key and secret are being successfully (looks like hard coded) you would be looking at further restrictions within the policy (such as principal or .

If the key and secret are not hard coded but instead passed in as environment variables, perform some debug to output the string values and validate these are what you expect. If they do not get passed into the SDK then it may be falling back to an instance role that is attached.

As a point of improvement, generally when interacting with the AWS SDK/CLI **from within AWS** (i.e. on an EC2 instance) you should [use a IAM role over an IAM user](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html#use-roles-with-ec2) as this will lead to less API credentials being managed/rotated. An IAM role will rotate temporary credentials for you every few hours.

Comment: It was hardcoded before, changed to environment variables but the same result. If permission is the issue, Why it's working from my local machine. Attached the permission which I have(Question edited)

Comment: Do you have the policy for `Ec2StartStop`?

Comment: Yes. You can see the permission list and that's why it's working from my local machine. Also, I created a Lambda function which also works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If the same credentials are working on local machine then it's probably not a permission issue, but just to further isolate the issue, you can try to run the AWS-GetCallerIdentity to check the credentials that are being used.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/get-caller-identity.html

In case if this does not help, create a new user and try giving full admin access and then using the credentials to see if this get's resolved. This will confirm whether we are facing a permission issue or not.